# Using a Riverpod State Provider to control changes in object

Tags: flutter, riverpod, state-management

I'm learning Riverpod, so I'm trying different things to see how it works.  Let's say I have the following class in my app;

```
class User {
  String _name = "";
  String _email = "";

  String get email => _email;

  String get name => _name;

  set email(String value) {
    _email = value;
  }

  set name(String name) {
    _name = name;
  }
}
```

So, I created a StateProvider to control the changes made in a User object:

```
final userProvider = StateProvider<User>((ref) {
  return User();
});
```

That is accessed this way:

```
final user = ref.watch(userProvider);
...
Text('Value: ${user.name}'),
```

However, when I change the provider's state, it does not rebuild my UI.

```
ref.read(userProvider.notifier).state.name = 'John Doe'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The literature is rushing to catch up with Remi's prolific development.  In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

Comment: And, you've perfectly demonstrated why StateProvider sucks.  You are mutating User, but that isn't enough to trigger an emit from a StateProvider.  You have to have overloaded the User equality notion.  Lots of ways to easily get this wrong.

Comment: This puzzled me because I expected the provider to control the state deeply. I'm sure providers will help a lot once I manage it. But I must admit, the learning curve has been super steep so far.

Comment: No, the trigger for a StateProvider is `.state = somethingNew`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you notice carefully, you are creating StateProvider of `User`. Therefore, changing single instance fields doent means it is different instance(new User) and that's why changing/updating fields doesn't refresh the UI. You need to pass new instance to update the UI.

You can do

```dart
final currentData = ref.read(userProvider);
ref.read(userProvider.notifier).state =
    User(name: 'new name', email: currentData.email);
```

But I prefer with `copyWith` method

```dart
final currentData = ref.read(userProvider);
 ref.read(userProvider.notifier).state =
     currentData.copyWith(name: 'new name');
```

or just use update

```dart
ref
    .read(userProvider.notifier)
    .update((state) => state.copyWith(name: 'new name'));
```

And the model class

```dart
class User {
  const User({
    this.name = '',
    this.email = '',
  });

  final String name;
  final String email;

  User copyWith({
    String? name,
    String? email,
  }) {
    return User(
      name: name ?? this.name,
      email: email ?? this.email,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Md. Yasin Sheikh! It does the job. Now, I understand that Riverpod makes a kind of "shallow" state management.

Comment: I *think* it uses equality, and if you don't have equality properly defined for your class, you run into problems.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I've tried with `Equatable` but it didn't work.